# How can I customize scrollbar sensitivity in editor property drawers in Unity3D?

Tags: unity

A custom property drawer, in my Unity `2017.3` project, has code like this in its `OnGUI` implementation:

```
public void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
    ...
    EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(maxX == 0);
    scrollX = (uint)GUI.HorizontalScrollbar(new Rect(xyPos + new Vector2(slHeight, normalizedSize), new Vector2(normalizedSize, slHeight)), scrollX, 1, 0, maxX + 1, GUI.skin.horizontalScrollbar);
    EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(maxY == 0);
    scrollY = (uint)GUI.VerticalScrollbar(new Rect(xyPos, new Vector2(slHeight, normalizedSize)), scrollY, 1, maxY + 1, 0, GUI.skin.verticalScrollbar);
    EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
    ...
}
```

But these scrollbars have a sensitivity of 10 (pressing the up/down, or left/right, buttons will change the current value by 10 in the respective direction). I need them to have a sensitivity of 1. How can I do it?